# No calcula la edad

Tags: javascript, asp.net

Tengo un problema con un script el cual me debería  calcular la edad cuando coloco la fecha de nacimiento pero me sale el error NaN o que esta fuera de rango. Declare edad como int y fechaNac le puse [DataType(DataType.Date)], y el formato en que me muestra para colocar la fecha es dd-MM-yyyy, no se si podrían ayudar a encontrar el problema

```js
function Edad() {
  const fechaNacimiento = document.getElementById("fechaNac");
  const edad = document.getElementById("edad");
  const calcularEdad = (fechaNacimiento) => {
    const fechaActual = new Date();
    const anoActual = parseInt(fechaActual.getFullYear());
    const mesActual = parseInt(fechaActual.getMonth()) + 1;
    const diaActual = parseInt(fechaActual.getDay());

    //01-01-2010
    const anoNacimiento = parseInt(String(fechaNacimiento).substring(6, 10));
    const mesNacimiento = parseInt(String(fechaNacimiento).substring(3, 5));
    const diaNacimiento = parseInt(String(fechaNacimiento).substring(0, 2));

    let edad = anoActual - anoNacimiento;
    if (mesActual < mesNacimiento) {
      edad--;
    } else if (mesActual == mesNacimiento) {
      if (diaActual < diaNacimiento) {
        edad--;
      }
    }
    return edad;
  }
  document.getElementById("edad").value = calcularEdad(this.value);
}
```

```html
<div class="form-group col-md-4 mb-4">
  <label asp-for="fechaNac" class="control-label"></label>
  <input asp-for="fechaNac" class="form-control" id="fechaNac" min="1930-01-01" oninput="Edad()" />
  <span asp-validation-for="fechaNac" class="text-danger"></span>
</div>
<div class="form-group col-md-2 mb-4">
  <label asp-for="edad" class="control-label"></label>
  <input asp-for="edad" class="form-control" id="edad" />
  <span asp-validation-for="edad" class="text-danger"></span>
</div>
```

Comment: Cuando llamas a calcularEdad al final le estás pasando como argumento this.value, pero no la veo definida por ningún sitio. De hecho en NaN te lo devuelve porque estás haciendo un calcularEdad(undefined) Si cambias this.value por el valor de fechaNacimiento te debería funcionar. Pon fechaNacimiento.value en lugar de this.value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tu error estaba en el this.value que debes colocarlo en el Input para usarlo tal cual
te dejo un ejemplo con tu codigo

```js
function Edad(valor) {
  const fechaNacimiento = document.getElementById("fechaNac");
  const edad = document.getElementById("edad");
  const calcularEdad = (fechaNacimiento) => {
    const fechaActual = new Date();
    const anoActual = parseInt(fechaActual.getFullYear());
    const mesActual = parseInt(fechaActual.getMonth()) + 1;
    const diaActual = parseInt(fechaActual.getDay());

    //01-01-2010
    const anoNacimiento = parseInt(String(fechaNacimiento).substring(6, 10));
    const mesNacimiento = parseInt(String(fechaNacimiento).substring(3, 5));
    const diaNacimiento = parseInt(String(fechaNacimiento).substring(0, 2));

    let edad = anoActual - anoNacimiento;
    console.log(anoNacimiento);
    if (mesActual < mesNacimiento) {
      edad--;
    } else if (mesActual == mesNacimiento) {
      if (diaActual < diaNacimiento) {
        edad--;
      }
    }
    return edad;
  }
  document.getElementById("edad").value = calcularEdad(valor);
}
```

```html
<div class="form-group col-md-4 mb-4">
  <label asp-for="fechaNac" class="control-label"></label>
  <input asp-for="fechaNac" class="form-control" id="fechaNac" min="1930-01-01" oninput="Edad(this.value)" />
  <span asp-validation-for="fechaNac" class="text-danger"></span>
</div>
<div class="form-group col-md-2 mb-4">
  <label asp-for="edad" class="control-label"></label>
  <input asp-for="edad" class="form-control" id="edad" />
  <span asp-validation-for="edad" class="text-danger"></span>
</div>
```

Comment: Realice el cambio que sugirió Robert Mengual y tambien el tuyo , y ambos funcionan, el problema es que me sale un año como respuesta. Por ejemplo yo naci el 08-05-1983 y me sale como respuesta 2016 en ambos casos.

Comment: Coloca esta fecha y prueba 10-11-2016 a mi me da 4

Comment: Valida con la respuesta que te deje, debes colocar la fecha completa

Comment: Coloque tu fecha (08-05-1983) y me da 38

Comment: tienes razon, si coloco una fecha en el codigo me da la respuesta correcta, pero en mi sistema me vota un año, porque podria ser?? el formato que esta con / y no con -??

Comment: Coloque 08/05/1983 e igual me dio, yo use tu script como base y al input coloque **Edad(this.value)** para que cuando ejecutes llames el valor que tengas en ese momento

Answer (score -2):

el problema era como se mostraba la fecha, envio la modificacion por si a alguien le sale el mismo error

```js
<script>

        function Edad(valor) {
            const fechaNacimiento = document.getElementById("fechaNac");
            const edad = document.getElementById("edad");
            const calcularEdad = (fechaNacimiento) => {
                const fechaActual = new Date();
                const anoActual = parseInt(fechaActual.getFullYear());
                const mesActual = parseInt(fechaActual.getMonth()) + 1;
                const diaActual = parseInt(fechaActual.getDay());

                //01-01-2010  2010-01-01
                const anoNacimiento = parseInt(String(fechaNacimiento).substring(0, 4));
                const mesNacimiento = parseInt(String(fechaNacimiento).substring(5, 7));
                const diaNacimiento = parseInt(String(fechaNacimiento).substring(8, 10));

                let edad = anoActual - anoNacimiento;
                console.log(anoNacimiento);
                if (mesActual < mesNacimiento) {
                    edad--;
                } else if (mesActual == mesNacimiento) {
                    if (diaActual < diaNacimiento) {
                        edad--;
                    }
                }
                return edad;                
            }
            document.getElementById("edad").value = calcularEdad(valor);
        }       

    </script>
```

Comment: Tu respuesta es solo codigo. Por favor mira [answer]. Se pide que expliques que hace este código (mas alla que a ti vos te parezca obvio, puede que otro usuario no lo vea tan simple).